# Select a particular item from selectInput() always when it is disabled by checkboxInput()

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinywidgets

Let say I have below `Shiny` app -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Choice a value", value = TRUE),
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                  "Transmission" = "am",
                  "Gears" = "gear"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$checkbox, {
            toggleState("variable")
        })
  }
)
```

Now I want that if `checkbox` is clicked then always `Cylinders` to be selected from `variable`.

With above approach this is not happening. Currently when user select other value i.g. `Gears` after enabling `variable`, and then again user goes on to `checkbox` to disable `variable`, the selection of `Gears` remains in UI, which I dont want and want to go back to `Cylinders` instantly every time `variable` is disabled.

Any pointer how to accomplish this will be highly appreciated.

**Updated after `bretauv's` reply -**

His answer works great with `shiny's` native `selectInput()`, however seems not working if I use `shinyWidgets` package's `pickerInput()` as below -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Choice a value", value = FALSE),
    pickerInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                  "Transmission" = "am",
                  "Gears" = "gear"),
                 width = "50%",
                selected = "gear")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
            if (input$checkbox) {
                    toggleState(id = "variable")
                } else {
                    toggleState(id = "variable")
                    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                                        inputId = "variable", label = NULL,  
                                        choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                                      "Transmission" = "am",
                                                      "Gears" = "gear"),
                                        selected = "Cylinders")
                }
            })
  }
)
```

Any pointer to resolve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `updateSelectInput` (don't forget to add `session` in `function(input, output, session)`). Also, you need to detail the situation when `checkboxInput` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

The code below should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Choice a value", value = FALSE),
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                  "Transmission" = "am",
                  "Gears" = "gear"),
                selected = "gear")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      if(input$checkbox == "TRUE"){
        toggleState(id = "variable")
      }

      else if(input$checkbox == "FALSE"){
        toggleState(id = "variable")
        updateSelectInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "variable",
                          choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                      "Transmission" = "am",
                                      "Gears" = "gear"),
                          selected = "cyl")
      }

    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works with selectInput() however failing to update properly for shinyWidgets:: pickerInput(). Is there any generic approach?

Comment: I can't figure out a way to do it, but an alternative would be to use `uiOutput` to display `pickerInput` if the checkbox is ticked (even if this is not optimal)